# RecyclerView getAdapterPosition() not working: returning correct position on first click and -1 on second click

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am deleting items from a Recylerview.  I implemented a  View.OnClickListener  in my ViewHolder. Then used setOnClickListener() on the view, and I am deleting the rows from the onClick method.

**When I click the view the first time the item deletes, on the second click I get an out of bounds exception as the getAdapterPosition() method returns -1.**

My implementation:

```
 public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {

imageView.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Log.v("clicker", "position is " + getAdapterPosition()); //returns correct index on first deletion and -1 on the second
              mItems.remove(getAdapterPosition);
        notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition);
    }
```

Note:

Curiously, using the deprecated getPosition() will return the incorrect index position, but it will nevertheless delete every item in the Recylcerview until the last item is left, wherein when the last item is clicked, it will crash because of an out of bounds index issue.

Tell me if you need more code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you double clicking while the deleted items is fading away? If so that's the right behavior since the item does not exist in the adapter anymore.

Comment: I am not double clicking on it, no matter how long I leave it, it will still produce the out of bounds exception.

Comment: removed item should disappear if you wait ~200ms (assuming your are using the default item animator). Can you share the adapter code ? (also the ItemAnimator code if you have a custom one)